# Set default checked Radio Button

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

I'm creating a `RadioGroup` with `RadioButton`s dynamically and need to have one radio button checked by default.

I've done this by using both `radioButton.setChecked(true)` and `radioButton.toggle();`

The problem I have is that when I at runtime select another radio button the first one stays checked so I end up with two checked radio buttons in the radio group.

Has anyone had this problem and know how to solve it?

```java
private RadioButton addRadioButton(String type, String price){
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(Order.this);
        radio.setText(type + " (" + Utils.formatCurrency(price) + ")");
        radio.setTextAppearance(Order.this, R.style.portalCellTextStyle);
        radio.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        radio.setTag(price);

        if(type.toLowerCase().equals("m"))
            radio.toggle();

        return radio;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you add radiobutton to correct radiogroup?

Answer (score 12):

I know I'm late but for those who search for the answer like me this can be useful.

When you add RadioButton to a RadioGroup, you must set the button checked after adding it to the parent like:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(getContext())
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
radioButton.setText("text");
mRadioGroup.addView(radioButton);
radioButton.setChecked(true);
```

If the view is checked before adding it to the parent, it will be impossible to uncheck it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply:

JAVA:

```
    radiogroup =(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    radiobutton1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
    radiobutton2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton2);

    if(your first assessment){
        radiobutton1.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        radiobutton2.setChecked(true);
    }
```

XML:

```
   <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, at first time load the screen check the position of In `Getview` method and then apply condition:

```
if (position == 0) {
  holder.act_delivery_rbtn.setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using one radio box for checking on and off, maybe you should use checkbox or toggle button instead.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Scroll down and see checkbox and toggle button.

When using radios you usually have more than one and choose between them. Like easy, medium, hard.

Replace

```
radio.toggle();
```

with

```
radio.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: I tried both and they both check the button but the button still stays checked if I check another one

Comment: are you adding them into single RadioGroup.?

Answer (score 1):

Just make checked = "true" in your code

Answer (score 0):

you should check it in radio group...

```
radiogroup.check(IdOfYourButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the clearCheck () function to clear the already checked buttons.I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be because I called the checked() method on the radio group straight after setting the OnCheckedChangeListener() causing it to be called immediately and throw a NPE for some reason.

Moved the checked() method call to just before the OnCheckedChangeListener() and it works now.

```
radios.check(2);
radios.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {   
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                }
            });

private RadioButton addRadioButton(String type, String price){
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(Order.this);
        radio.setText(type + " (" + Utils.formatCurrency(price) + ")");
        radio.setTextAppearance(Order.this, R.style.portalCellTextStyle);
        radio.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10);
        radio.setTag(price);

        if(type.toLowerCase().equals("m"))
            radio.setId(2);

        return radio;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in `Xml` add  `android:checkedButton="@+id/storeRB"` to `RadioGroup`

```
 <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/storeTypeRG"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/storeRB"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text2">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/storeRB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_bg"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/store_str"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text2"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/hyperRB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_bg"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/hyper_str"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/storeRB"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text2" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/restaurantRB"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:button="@drawable/radio_button_bg"
                    android:paddingStart="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/restaurant_str"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/text2"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/hyperRB"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/text2" />
            </RadioGroup>
```

[image]